# How to get user PC ip from server in php

Tags: php

Suppose user's PC IP is 192.168.10.81(IPv4 in his personal PC's windows)

When this user browse `www.mydomain.com` I want to get this `IP` from `www.mydomain.com/index.php` using PHP

Is it possible? If possible, How?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` ?

Comment: Is the domain in the same internal network? Sounds like you want to get the private IP of the PC, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: It gives real ip over which browsing this domain. Not personal pc's IP

Comment: I know that this answer is copied from the other answer so have some courtesy to provide a credit link to real author and also, you should be explaining what the code does rather than just writing ***Try this code...***

Answer (score 0):

**$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']** is the only reliable IP address you'll get - it's extracted directly from the TCP stack and is where the current connection was established from. This means if the user is connecting via a proxy, you'll get the proxy's address, not the user's.

Any of the other header-based ones are unreliable, as HTTP headers are trivial to forge. You can use the information from them, if you'd like, as long as you don't TRUST it.

Try this code:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

 if ($referred == "") {
  $referrer = "This page was accessed directly";
  }

echo "<b>Visitor IP address:</b><br/>" . $ip . "<br/>";
echo "<b>Browser (User Agent) Info:</b><br/>" . $browser . "<br/>";
echo "<b>Referrer:</b><br/>" . $referrer . "<br/>";
?>
```

**Output like this:**

> Visitor IP address:
>   127.0.0.1
>
> Browser (User Agent) Info: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
>
> Referrer:
>
> http://www.hexrara.com